# Как изменить цвет самих кнопок navigation bar color (java android)?

Tags: java, android

хотел поменять цвет кнопок именно в панели navigation bar color, но что-то не получается, вот прошу у вас помощи :)

[image: (картинка)]

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.klav));
        }
    }catch (Exception r){

    }
    try {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        Window win = getWindow();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 27) {
            //this here works
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
            //win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        } else {
            //this here works
            win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).